# How to lock the zoom ratio in acrobat (reader or pro)

Tags: zooming, acrobat

I'm viewing a non-secured (i.e. no passwords applied for any option) pdf file in acrobat Pro 11.

I'm viewing the file at 144% magnification/zoom level. But whenever I click another bookmark (from bookmarks panel) or another page (from pages panel), the zoom is reset to full page (or whatever is set in 'Initial View' tab of the Document Properties dialouge. How can I avoid this. I mean, I want that whenever I navigate to other page or bookmark, the zoom shouldn't change to any other than whatever the current zoom percentage is.

Answer (score 3):

I found a circumvention: Use the *free* Foxit PDF Reader (https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/pdf-reader/)

As I type this, I'm running version 7. In **Preferences** > **Page Display**, select **Forbid the change of the current zoom factor during execution of 'Goto destination' actions...**

[image]

I tested this with a PDF that was annoying the heck out me by changing my preferred zoom factor every time I clicked a bookmark. The free Foxit Reader blocked bookmarks from changing the current zoom level.

I also have Adobe Acrobat. Although it is in theory a full-featured PDF editor, it doesn't provide any straightforward way to reconfigure the PDF's bookmarks *Zoom level: fit page* setting.

Using Foxit Reader doesn't fix the PDF's unwanted bookmark behavior. But it does enable one to view a PDF without having to constantly put the zoom value back where one wants it after clicking a bookmark...

Comment: It works. Also works on PDF-XChange.

Comment: This is the best answer. Bye bye, Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 1):

​Hey, the problem was troubling me too much and in the end I could SOLVE the same (google didn't help).

First, I had tried changing the settings properly at two places, in Adobe Preferences> Page Display. And in File Properties> Initial View. But still when I clicked any bookmark, it zoomed back to 'Fit to Page'.

What solved my problem, in the end, is that I selected any/all bookmarks (Ctrl+A) in the bookmarks palette, and then clicked the bookmarks palette menu (on the top left side of bookmarks palette)> Properties> Actions tab and there deleted (or edited) the actions present.

That's it. Thank you guys for your lovely answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Every time I opened the PDF, it zoomed to "Fit width."  Also, after opening, I could set the zoom to whatever I wanted and everything was fine unless I scrolled to the very top of the document where it would again zoom to "Fit width."

I tried adjusting document properties, Acrobat preferences, even bookmark properties (bookmarks can specify zoom level instead of just saying "Inherit").

Finally, I switched the navigation panel from Bookmark to Page view.  Right clicked on the first page icon and checked properties. There was a "Fit width" zoom setting that executed on "Page Open".  I deleted that action and have had no problems with that file since.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed an editable PDF's bookmark-zoom behavior as follows:

## Download and Install JPDFBookmarks

These download links valid as of 24 April, 2019:

- http://codebyjoshua.blogspot.com/2012/02/easily-change-pdf-zoom-level-and-name.html
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpdfbookmarks/

## Open the PDF in JPDFBookmarks

1. In a PDF editor such as Acrobat, modify one of your bookmarks to have the type of zoom you want. This enables you to copy the desired zoom settings in subsequent steps.
2. In PDFBookmarks, open the zip file, extract the files, then open the PDF file JPDFBookmarks.
3. Dump the bookmark data to a text file using JPDFBookmarks with the command **Tools** > **Dump**.

## Find/Replace the Bookmark Settings

1. Open the PDF dump file in a text editor, then find the bookmark you edited.
2. Find/Replace the bookmark settings:

   a. Copy the correct portion of the text associated with your edited bookmark that is different from all the other bookmarks. For example,`TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0`.

   b. Find/Replace the other setting on all the other bookmarks, such as `FitWidth, -6`.
3. You can change the name of any bookmark while you're here.
4. Save the changes to the text file.
5. In JPDFBookmarks, load the bookmark data back using **Tools** > **Load**
6. In JPDFBookmarks, save the file as a modified version of the original PDF.

The bookmark zoom behaviors have been fixed.